# Possible to add an object to SQLAlchemy session without explicit session.add()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a number of classes that are mapped to tables with SQLAlchemy (non-declaratively if that matters). Because I'd like the application to be unit-testable, all SQLAlchemy session interaction is isolated into a single class. Using the app goes something like this:

```
m = Model("mysql://localhost/mydb")
s1 = Service("somename")
m.session.add(s1)
s1 is m.get_service("somename") # True
```

It's actually more streamlined than that, but work with me here.

Is it possible to skip the session.add() step? In other words, if I instantiate a mapped class, is it possible for that be automatically added to the active SQLAlchemy session (if any)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically add a SQLAlchemy object to the session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873251/how-to-automatically-add-a-sqlalchemy-object-to-the-session)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQLAlchemy you can only do this with tables by binding their metadata to an engine. This does not work with the ORM part of SQLALchemy.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html?highlight=metadata#binding-metadata-to-an-engine-or-connection

One approach to this sort of thing is to use a scoped session that can be accessed anywhere.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html?highlight=scoped%20session#sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session

Comment: So, "No" is the answer to my question, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, not all the time.
If you have defined relationship between child and parent models, or many-to-many relationship, you only have to .add the parent objects explicitly. The child objects are added automatically when assigned the attribute parent, which is always already in db/session. Example:

```
a1 = Author(name='Pynchon') # out of session
session.add(a1) # in session
b1 = Book(name='Gravity`s Rainbow') # out of session
b1.author = a1 #in session
a2 = session.query(Author).filter(name='Eco').one() # in session
b2 = Book(name='Baudolino') # out of session
b2.author = a2 # in session
```

Of course, you need to specify the 'author' relationship between the mappers beforehand.